# Mimic the Figma "clip content : off" behaviour in CSS

Tags: css, user-interface, overflow, clip, figma

I'm a designer and it’s been several times that developpers had troubles implementing my designs because I set the clip content to off on my frames to have shadows or blur that fade smoothly outside of the div.
Is there an way to mimic the Figma's “clip content : off” behaviour with CSS ?

I suggested the "overflow" property but tech people told me that it's not a solution.

Thanks !

Comment: Have you seen what the code looks like for this design in Dev Mode?